# Booking system search using solr

Tags: solr

I am working on a booking system where in booking is done based on dates selected as start time till end time and I maintain inventory table for availability with a slot datetime column that gives me the value of availability of inventory for that time slot.

We currently do a range query in sql but would like to have this inventory data indexed in solr for faster range query searches.

The problem I see is that whenever a booking is done the inventory data has to be updated and won't this constant update affect solrs performance?

Answer (score 0):

This is what Solr's *[Near Real Time Search](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Near+Real+Time+Searching)* has been built for. You will need to fine tune this, but you should not face performance impediments, if used right.

> Near Real Time (NRT) search means that documents are available for search almost immediately after being indexed: additions and updates to documents are seen in 'near' real time. Solr does not block updates while a commit is in progress. Nor does it wait for background merges to complete before opening a new search of indexes and returning.
>
> With NRT, you can modify a commit command to be a soft commit, which avoids parts of a standard commit that can be costly. You will still want to do standard commits to ensure that documents are in stable storage, but soft commits let you see a very near real time view of the index in the meantime.

When searching for further resources about this topic on the web, you should stumble over these articles

- [Hard commits, soft commits and transaction logs](https://lucidworks.com/blog/understanding-transaction-logs-softcommit-and-commit-in-sorlcloud/) by Erick Erickson
- [Benchmarking the new Solr ‘Near Realtime’ Improvements](https://lucidworks.com/blog/benchmarking-the-new-solr-near-realtime-improvements/) by Mark Miller
- and of course [the Solr reference](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Near+Real+Time+Searching)